# What does this PHP code mean?

Tags: php

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/yahooPHP/lib/Yahoo.inc';
```

This line is in one file in one directory and I am having trouble determining how to reference a file in another directory.

What does this expression mean and does it imply references must only be within the same directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`__FILE__`** is a [**Magic Constant**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that correspond to the full path to the file into which it is written.

This means that **`dirname(__FILE__)`** points to the directory into which your current file *(the one in which this is written)* is.

So, `dirname(__FILE__).'/yahooPHP/lib/Yahoo.inc'` points to :

- The directory into which this line is written,
- And, then, the `yahooPHP` subdirectory of that directory
- and the `lib` subdirectory of `yahooPHP`
- and the `Yahoo.inc` file into that `lib` directory.

Basically, you have :

```
your-file.php
yahooPHP/
    lib/
        Yahoo.inc
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

> A key problem to hierarchical include
>   trees is that PHP processes include
>   paths relative to the original file,
>   not the current including file.
>
> A solution to that, is to prefix all
>   include paths with:
>   <?php
>   str_replace('//','/',dirname(**FILE**));
>   ?>
>
> this will generate a base path
>   relative to the current file, which
>   will then allow an include behavior
>   similar to C/C++.
>
> thus, to include a file that is 1 in
>   the parent directory:
>   <?php
>   require_once(
>   str_replace('//','/',dirname(**FILE**).'/')
>   .'../parent.php'); ?>
>
> to include a file that is in the same
>   directory:
>   <?php require_once(
>   str_replace('//','/',dirname(**FILE**).'/')
>   .'neighbor.php'); ?>
>
> to include a file that is in a
>   subdirectory:
>   <?php require_once(
>   str_replace('//','/',dirname(**FILE**).'/')
>   .'folder/sub.php'); ?>
>
> Notice that all paths we reference
>   must NOT begin with a /, and must be
>   relative to the current file, in order
>   to concatenate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the [specification](http://.net/manual/en/function.require.php).
This is actually an example of including specified resource into your PHP script, along with retrieving parent folder path and string concatenation. This works as follow:

```
require = add file to your PHP script (similar to `include`)
dirname() = get the parent directory of specified path
__FILE__ = this will be resolved to absolute path of the current file
.'/yahooPHP/lib/Yahoo.inc' = string concatenation, so this part simply adds file's path to the rest of the string
```

So in the end you end up adding a file pointed by a path to the Yahoo.inc file (which should be found in directory relative to the parent directory).